# How to select records testing bits in BINARY column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary, bit

I have 2 tables: one of them contains column binary(128), where every bit is some flag. Also I have other table contains list of bit positions which need to check in query.

This is example how I do the query for one bit. 
How to do it universally, i.e. to select records testing bits in positions from the second table?
Should it be a function? what?

```
DECLARE @nByteNum      integer
DECLARE @nBitNumInByte integer
DECLARE @nMask         integer
DECLARE @nBigBitNum    integer 

declare @t table(id int not null identity, id1 int, banner binary(128))
declare @bitpositions table(id int not null identity, position int)

insert into @bitpositions(position) values(8)
insert into @bitpositions(position) values(24)
insert into @bitpositions(position) values(30)

insert into @t(id1, banner)
select 1, 0x0
union all
select 1, 0x000100FF
union all
select 1, 0x010200FF
union all
select 10, 0x010208
union all
select 10, 0x000100
union all
select 10, 0x040000

select * from @t

-- This is for one bit
SET @nBigBitNum= 24
SET @nByteNum= @nBigBitNum/8
SET @nBitNumInByte= @nBigBitNum % 8      -- 0,1...6,7
SET @nMask = POWER(2, @nBitNumInByte ) -- 128,64,... 2,1
SET @nByteNum= @nByteNum +1

select * from @t where SUBSTRING(banner, @nByteNum,1)&@nMask=@nMask
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operations in SQL Server do not work on BINARY data in the way that you are expecting.  They work on integer datatypes only as noted on the MSDN page for [& (Bitwise AND)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx).

The general syntax for checking bitmasked values in a query is: `WHERE {Column} & {BitMaskedValue} = {BitMaskedValue}`.

Look at the following examples using your desired scenario of trying to find records that have bit positions 8 and 16 turned on.

```
-- 24 = 16 + 8
SELECT 24 & 16 -- 16
SELECT 24 & 8 -- 8
SELECT 24 & 17 -- 16
SELECT 24 & 32 -- 0
SELECT 24 & 26 -- 24
```

Comment: Yes, but this query works correctly:  select * from @t where SUBSTRING(banner, @nByteNum,1)&@nMask=@nMask;. Another question how to optimize queries on a large tables? any tricks? :-)